# PayPal Return URL not called, except when payer_status = verified?

Tags: paypal, payment

This is a strange one. The IPN is called and executes correctly after the payment but the Return URL is not called, except when payer_status=verified, is that just a coincidence? Anybody else found this happening? Only been happening for a month or two.

Thanks for any info,

Mark.

Comment: UPDATE: For others having similar issues... It is sort of high-lighted by payer_status, if the purchaser uses Guest Checkout, e.g. pays with a credit card, the RETURN URL is NOT triggered. I disagreed with PayPal, and stated that it should always return if the URL has been set. I said that the return to the website would acknowledge that the sale has been accepted by us... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't heard anyone else reporting this yet, but if you can open up a ticket with [PayPal's MTS](http://www.paypal.com/mts) we can look into this.  By opening up a ticket, if the issue is identified as a bug you will be notified once the issue is fixed.

Comment: Done and got a response, see above. Thank you.